# How to print entire line in the file when a string match is found?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to implement a function that searches a text file and prints (to standard output) any lines in the file that contains all of the characters specified in a string (upper and lower case letters, special chars, and digits).

For example, if file contains 3 lines:

```
BcdXYZ
bcd$
XYZcbd$
```

and the specified string to match is `b$cd`, then the output should be:

```
bcd$
XYZcbd$
```

since only these 2 lines contain all of the 4 characters specified.

Here is my code:

```
public static void printMatch(String theFile, String patternToFind) {

    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(patternToFind);
    Matcher m = patt.matcher(theFile);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }

}
```

What should I do? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your file by `\n` first and then match for every line, or you can expand your patern like this: `Pattern.compile("(\\n{0,1}.*(" + patternToFind + ").*\\n{0,1})");`

With this addition you can then use `m.group(1)` for your entire line and `m.group(2)` for the exact match.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented the suggestion but it outputs exact match only. If I have file with "AbcXYZ\nabc\nXYZcba" and patternToFind = "abc" is prints out only the second line "abc" when it should also print the third line which also contains a,b, c. How can I do that?

Comment: Ah okay. You want to match the characters in any order. Than use this line: `Pattern.compile("(\\n{0,1}.*([" + patternToFind + "]{" + patternToFind.length() + "}).*\\n{0,1})"); `